# Error only in Android versions below 4

Tags: android

I got error on device and emulator with android version 2.3.3, but on device and emulator with Android version 4 - no error...
LogCat say:

```
 08-12 19:07:45.182: E/AndroidRuntime(352): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-12 19:07:45.182: E/AndroidRuntime(352): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-12 19:07:45.182: E/AndroidRuntime(352):  at android.app.WallpaperManager.setBitmap(WallpaperManager.java:484)
08-12 19:07:45.182: E/AndroidRuntime(352):  at com.zznob.lwpchanger.SWpJob$ParseSite.onPostExecute(SWpJob.java:96)
08-12 19:07:45.182: E/AndroidRuntime(352):  at com.zznob.lwpchanger.SWpJob$ParseSite.onPostExecute(SWpJob.java:1)
08-12 19:07:45.182: E/AndroidRuntime(352):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
08-12 19:07:45.182: E/AndroidRuntime(352):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
08-12 19:07:45.182: E/AndroidRuntime(352):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
08-12 19:07:45.182: E/AndroidRuntime(352):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-12 19:07:45.182: E/AndroidRuntime(352):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-12 19:07:45.182: E/AndroidRuntime(352):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-12 19:07:45.182: E/AndroidRuntime(352):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-12 19:07:45.182: E/AndroidRuntime(352):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-12 19:07:45.182: E/AndroidRuntime(352):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-12 19:07:45.182: E/AndroidRuntime(352):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-12 19:07:45.182: E/AndroidRuntime(352):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Code with error:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap)
        {
            if(!isCancelled()){
                try{
                    wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap); <- Error on Android version 2.2-2.3
                }
                catch(IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
        }
```

Build with API version 8... Any idea?

Class full code - http://pastebin.com/iwgYbPfb

Comment: I think more code is necessary - where is wallpaperManager coming from?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/iwgYbPfb - class code

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive%28android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent%29 says something about the lifecycle of the broadcast receiver - perhaps this is the reason and it is a device-dependent issue?

Comment: i have this error only on devices with android 2.2-2.3, on 4.0 all ok..